# Выравнивание list-style-image в списке

Tags: html, css

В верстке меню такого вида
[image]

не получается выравнять маркеры списка, чтобы она находились напротив элементов 
http://jsfiddle.net/YjnBe/ 
подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фоновую картинкой вставлять для каждого элемента списка.
Позиционирование делается через background-position

Comment: то есть, если задано через list-style-image, никак не спозиционировать?

Comment: спасибо, всё получилось)

Comment: А как получилось то, расскажите, мне то же интересно !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YjnBe/5/